# Annihilators and semisimple rings

Tags: ring-theory

Let $R$ be a semisimple ring and let $I$ be a left ideal of $R$. Denote $\text{ann}_l(S)$, resp. $\text{ann}_r(S)$, for the left (resp. right) annihilator of a left ideal $S$ of $R$. Any tips on how to show that $\text{ann}_l(\text{ann}_r(I)) \subseteq I$?

(the reverse inclusion is straightforward)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $R$ is semisimple, $I=Re$ for some idempotent $e$.

It's not hard to show that $ann_r(Re)=(1-e)R$ and $ann_l(eR)=R(1-e)$.

Then $ann_l(ann_r(Re))=ann_l((1-e)R)=R(1-(1-e))=Re=I$

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is there a way of solving this without using idempotents?

Comment: @J.Bosser No other elementary approach occurs to me.  The lemma above is provable by an undergraduate... Are you stuck or something?

Comment: No, it's not that. It's just the fact that I've never seen the correspondence between ideals of semisimple rings and idempotent elements.

Comment: So your initial approach is completely new to me.

Comment: Oh, that's another elementary fact: every left ideal of a semisimple ring is a summand (surely you know that) and every summand of a ring with identity is generated by an idempotent.  That might be new for you, but it is super useful and definitely worth proving for yourself. Just do this: if $A\oplus B=R$, you can write $1=a+b$ and prove that $a$ is an idempotent and that $A=Ra$

Comment: The general theorem is that idempotents in $End_R(M)$ correspond to direct-sum decompositions of $_RM$.

Comment: Thanks for the information!

Comment: @J.Bosser No problem!